# How can I reduce my work to get the result automatically?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex

I want to find the locus of point present of the complex `z` so that 
$$|z + 2| + |z - 2| = 18. $$
I tried by hand

```
ComplexExpand[Abs[z + 2] == 18 - Abs[z - 2] /. z :> (x + y I)];
Simplify[#^2 & /@ %]
Expand[Simplify[(9 Sqrt[4 - 4 x + x^2 + y^2])^2 - (81 - 2 x)^2]]
Simplify[1/6237 (-6237 + 77 x^2 + 81 y^2)]
```

> -1 + x^2/81 + y^2/77

How can I reduce my work to get the result automatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GroebnerBasis[]` does the job:

```
First[GroebnerBasis[ComplexExpand[Abs[z + 2] + Abs[z - 2] == 18 /. z :> (x + I y)], {x, y}]]
   -6237 + 77 x^2 + 81 y^2

ContourPlot[% == 0, {x, -9, 9}, {y, -9, 9}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image: ellipse]

Comment: Is it always the first element? I admit I don't understand the documentation on `GroebnerBasis` very well: "The Gröbner basis in general depends on the ordering assigned to monomials. This ordering is affected by the ordering of the $x_i$." And then there's the `MonomialOrder` option too. How to tell which one to pick?

Comment: @Roman, often it is, but sometimes you have to look for the "rationalized" expression in the list returned by `GroebnerBasis[]`. The reason for someone wanting to set `MonomialOrder` is that both the efficiency of the method and the simplicity of the results (that is, the *basis*) can depend on the choice of order in eliminating the variables.

Answer (score 2):

In general, you can use `Solve`:

```
Solve[ComplexExpand[Abs[z + 2] + Abs[z - 2] == 18 /. z -> x + I y], y]
```

> $\left\{\left\{y\to -\frac{1}{9} \sqrt{77} \sqrt{81-x^2}\right\},\left\{y\to \frac{1}{9}\sqrt{77} \sqrt{81-x^2}\right\}\right\}$

Then you can for example do

```
DeleteDuplicates[y^2 /. %]
```

> {77/81 (81 - x^2)}

to find something close to your result.

Answer (score 1):

```
Reduce[Abs[z + 2] + Abs[z - 2] == 18, z]
```

> -9 <= Re[z] <= 9 && (Im[z] == -(1/9) Sqrt[6237 - 77 Re[z]^2] || Im[z] == 1/9 Sqrt[6237 - 77 Re[z]^2])